# Python Text file to List not dividing up

Tags: python, list, text

How would I modify this program so that my list doesn't keep spitting out the extra text per line? The program should only output the single line that the user wants to display rather than the quotes that were added to the list before. The program will read a textfile indicated by the user, then it will display the selected line for the user and exit up a '0' input.
This is in python

```
import string
count = 0
#reads file
def getFile():
    while True:
        inName = input("Please enter file name: ")
        try:
            inputFile = open(inName, 'r')

        except:
            print ("I cannot open that file. Please try again.")
        else:
            break
    return inputFile

inputFile = getFile()
inputList = inputFile.readlines()

for line in inputList:
    count = count + 1
print("There are", count, "lines.")

while True:
    lineChoice = int(input("Please select line[0 to exit]: "))
    if lineChoice == 0:
        break
    elif lineChoice > 0 and lineChoice <= count:
        print(inputList[:lineChoice - 1])
    else:
        print("Invalid selection[0 to exit]")
```

Output:

```
Please enter file name: quotes.txt

There are 16 lines.

Please select line[0 to exit]: 1

[]

Please select line[0 to exit]: 2

['Hakuna Matata!\n']

Please select line[0 to exit]: 3

['Hakuna Matata!\n', 'All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them.\n']

Please select line[0 to exit]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Python String strip() Method

example usage

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str = "0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
print str.strip( '0' )
```

output:

```
this is string example....wow!!!
```

The example is from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, you want to only display the single line corresponding to the number the user entered.

Currently, you are using slicing to get all the lines before and including the one you want. Remove the colon in your print inputList index:

`elif lineChoice > 0 and lineChoice <= count:
        print(inputList[lineChoice - 1].strip())`

To remove the quotes and new line characters etc., use the string method .strip()